# Defaulted hash keys disappearing in Perl

Tags: perl, associative-array

I think my Perl is getting rusty :)

This following script is supposed to iterate through a directory of text files containing LDAP records for a particular user to extract specific information. I am experiencing an issue where the 'group' hash key is removed from the hash ref if the 'productfamily' attribute does not exist in the file.

```
#!/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use File::Basename;

sub extract_val {
    my $line = shift;
    return (split /\:/, $line)[1];
}

my @ldif_files = <tmp/*.ldif>;
my $line_ctr = 0;
my @record_ctr;

for my $ldif_file (@ldif_files) {

    open my $fh,'<', $ldif_file or die "Cannot open file: $!";
    my @contents = <$fh>;
    close $fh;

    my $user_record = {
       'file'    => basename $ldif_file,
       'group'   => 'BP',
       'uid'     => '',
       'fname'   => '',
       'lname'   => '',
       'company' => '',
    };

    for my $line (@contents){
        chomp $line;
        $user_record->{'uid'}     = extract_val($line) if $line =~ /^uid\:/;
        $user_record->{'fname'}   = extract_val($line) if $line =~ /^givenname\:/;
        $user_record->{'lname'}   = extract_val($line) if $line =~ /^sn\:/;
        $user_record->{'company'} = extract_val($line) if $line =~ /^o\:/;
        $user_record->{'group'}   = 'EU' if $line =~ /^productfamily\:/;
    }

    print Dumper $user_record;

    last if $line_ctr++ == 10;
}
```

**Output Examples**

Here are two representative samples from the output.

'group' hash key present if productfamily attribute exists in LDAP record.

```
$VAR1 = {
    'group' => 'EU',
    'uid' => 'abcdef',
    'lname' => 'SMITH',
    'fname' => 'JOHN',
    'file' => 'abcdef.ldif',
    'company' => 'Some Company'
    };
```

'group' hash key missing if productfamily attribute does NOT exist in LDAP record.

```
$VAR1 = {
    'uid' => 'uvwxyz',
    'lname' => 'Bar',
    'fname' => 'Foo',
    'file' => 'uvwxyz.ldif',
    'company' => 'Another Company'
    };
```

Perl version is 5.8.5 on Solaris 5.9.

There are approximately 6000 files, but I have limited the number of loop iterations to 10 since the problem shows up early in my data files.

Comment: Try stepping through the code in the perl debugger: `perl -d program.pl`. It's a small enough chunk of code, you should be able to figure it out in about 5 minutes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`basename` doesn't have a prototype, so it slurps up all your hash entries.  What you wrote is equivalent to

```
my $user_record = {
   'file'    => basename($ldif_file,
                         'group'   => 'BP',
                         'uid'     => '',
                         'fname'   => '',
                         'lname'   => '',
                         'company' => ''),
};
```

Comment: Nice! That was it. I surrounded $ldif_file with parens and the key stayed. I knew my Perl was getting rusty :)